# How to make this two query in one statement. one is for search and one is for normal query. i made this on search system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

please help  me for this $query is a search query which is running well but while i joint in $query22 it's not get result well. i am in trouble how to do it please help me for this. Thanks

```
$query ="select * from user where user_name LIKE '%$ageeee%' OR user_id LIKE '%$ageeee%' ";

$query22="SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) FROM user u WHERE u.refered = user.user_id and launch=1)as ref , (SELECT COUNT(ui.`global`) FROM user ui WHERE ui.global = user.user_id and launch=1) as glo, user_id , mod_date BETWEEN '2017-08-16 12:00:14' AND '2117-08-17 15:55:07'  FROM user  HAVING ref <6 and glo < 6";
```

Comment: I think you should try to in $query22 replace "HAVING" with "WHERE". as it is aggregate function.

Comment: i make this but got error :( 

 SELECT (select * from user where user_id LIKE '%517%'), (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) FROM user u WHERE u.refered = user.user_id and launch=1)as ref , (SELECT COUNT(ui.`global`) FROM user ui WHERE ui.global = user.user_id and launch=1) as glo, user_id , mod_date BETWEEN '2017-08-16 12:00:14' AND '2117-08-17 15:55:07'  FROM user  HAVING ref <6 and glo < 6

Comment: 1. Instead of `HAVING` user `WHERE`.  2. Replace `ref` and `glo` with the query used is select clause. 3. Put `between` clause inside `where`.

Comment: Hello @Utsav will you send code please

Comment: Please avoid variable names like `$query22` (and, to a lesser extent, `$query`). You're going to give the next person working on your code a headache. That person might be you in a month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you rest of the table structure and columns are correct, these are the basic mistakes. Try this

```
SELECT  
     (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) 
        FROM user u 
        WHERE u.refered = user.user_id and launch=1
      ) as ref 
     ,(SELECT COUNT(ui.`global`) 
        FROM user ui 
        WHERE ui.global = user.user_id and launch=1
       ) as glo
    ,user_id
    ,mod_date 
FROM user  
WHERE
mod_date BETWEEN '2017-08-16 12:00:14' 
             AND '2117-08-17 15:55:07'
    AND
        (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) 
        FROM user u 
        WHERE u.refered = user.user_id and launch=1
        ) <6 
    AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(ui.`global`) 
        FROM user ui 
        WHERE ui.global = user.user_id and launch=1
        ) < 6
```